# Evaluation $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^{\log m}}{m^{\log n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Evaluate where $m>1$ is constant
>
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^{\log m}}{m^{\log n}}$$

I tried to use L'Hopital rule but it didn't work.

I have no idea how to evaluate this limit. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Ignore the limit for a moment and really think about the problem.

Comment: Use $a^b =e^{b\ln(a)}.$

Comment: @anomaly I'm thinking over an hour about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence is constant. Take the logarithm of each part and compare.

Comment: I will try that now

Comment: Can I do that: $$\frac{\log(n^{\log m})}{\log(m^{\log n})}$$?

Comment: You *can*, but the point of taking the logarithm is to be able to compare the numerator and denominator. Simplify each part separately.

Comment: Yes, from here it's easy, thank you

Answer (score 3):

$$n^{\log m} = e^{\log n \log m} = m ^{\log n}$$

Comment: beautiful$~~~~~~$

Comment: That's the way I would proceed.  +1